# Laravel: How get the value of a select (Drop-Down Lists) to bind with the model?

Tags: php, laravel

something like...
in the view

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'expense/add', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-signin'), array('role'=>'form'))}}
      <select id="expense_category_id" class="form-control">
      @foreach($data['categories'] as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    {{Form::submit('submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'))}}
  {{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: If you use the `Form::select()` helper, it'll do it for you. It has limitations, but for a basic form like yours, it'll save you code and give you extra functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controller:

```
$data['categories'] = Category::lists('name', 'id');
```

If you are using the [attribute](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) Category model controller:

```
$data['categories'] = Category::get()->lists('name', 'id');
```

view:

```
{{ Form::select('expense_category_id', $data['categories'], null, array('class' => 'form-control') }}
```

For laravel5.3 use pluck.

`$data['categories'] = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id');`
[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

You can try.

Comment: I don't understand the part in the controller... If I want to get text I use `Input::get(nameOfInputfield)`. What is the equivalent for a drop-down list with select?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can pass the categories from your controller like this:

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

And inside your blade generate the dropdown like this:

```
{!! Form::select('category', $categories->lists('name', 'id'), Input::old('category'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```